# variable function jquery cant find the value from other function

Tags: jquery

why variable `check` gives only 0 on the screen even when I press an input field?

```
$(function() {
        var check;
        if (!check){ // checking if check is null (changed to 0)
            check = 0;
        }
        $('input').bind('focus',function() {
            if(check == 0){ //if I pressed on an input field change check to 1
                check = 1;  
            }
            if(check == 1){ 
            setTimeout(function(){ 
               // $('#header').css('display','none');
                check = 2; //if check is already 1 change it to 2.
            }, 200);
            }else{ 
                //$('#header').css('display','none');
            }

        });
    $('.check').html(check);
});
```

script stays under the div. (bottom of the page)

Comment: any error in browser console..?

Comment: could you provide a fiddle?

Comment: check my answer you may need to know what your error is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to set html for `.check` always when you change the value for `check`, there is no auto data-binding like angular in jquery see thid [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/naeemshaikh27/2hgpjvuL/1/)

```
$(function() {
        var check;
        if (!check){ // checking if check is null (changed to 0)
            check = 0;
        }
        $('input').bind('focus',function() {
            if(check == 0){ //if I pressed on an input field change check to 1
                check = 1;  
            }
            if(check == 1){ 
            setTimeout(function(){ 
               // $('#header').css('display','none');
                check = 2; //if check is already 1 change it to 2.
                $('.check').html(check);
            }, 200);
            }else{ 
                //$('#header').css('display','none');
            }
 $('.check').html(check);
        });

});
```

Comment: but if i'm using the check variable in other function. i get 0 insteed of 1 or 2

Comment: where is the other function

Comment: where the check html stays (on my code) i need to put it into the function where you put the check html? then it works i think ^^

Answer (score 0):

*Your code is fine!* you only need to **put** `$('.check').html(check);` **inside your event listener function** like this:

```
$(function() {
        var check;
        if (!check){ // checking if check is null (changed to 0)
            check = 0;
        }
        $('input').bind('focus',function() {

            if(check == 0){ //if I pressed on an input field change check to 1
                check = 1;  
            }
            if(check == 1){ 
            setTimeout(function(){ 
               // $('#header').css('display','none');
                check = 2; //if check is already 1 change it to 2.

            }, 200);
            }else{ 
                //$('#header').css('display','none');
            }
            $('.check').html(check);
        });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Without a fiddle it is hard to guess, but my bet would be that you are not upgrading the value of $('.check') in the focus event handler. You are only setting once (to 0). You should also add

```
$('.check').html(check);
```

to the function handling the `bind` event (e.g. after the else branch, and possibly also inside the timeout handling function), because changes in the value of the `check` variable are not automatically reflected to the HTML.